# when to use Repository methods and when to use mongoTemplate?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on `Spring data mongo` with my `Spring MVC` application. I need to understand which is the correct way to improve performance if I wish to use multiple criteria's.

- Do I need to go for `Repository` methods? Or
- Do I need to go for `MongoTemplate`/`MongoOperations`?

Which is advisable to use to improve performance with many contional criteria's ?

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository) was helpful for this question.

Answer (score 0):

from their doc

> By default the repositories will get a MongoTemplate Spring bean wired
>   that is called mongoTemplate, so you only need to configure
>   mongo-template-ref explicitly if you deviate from this convention.

if we are talking about performance it is not dependant which of two you will choose.  The performance depends on your indexes.