# Cannot load bean in different package in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to load beans from a different package on a Spring boot application. Here's my main class, that lives in ***com.xyz.app*** package:

***Application.java***:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.xyz.app.repository" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
                            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    context.getBean(MyInterfaceRepository.class).loadData();
 }
```

The interface ***MyInterfaceRepository.java*** is inside the ***com.xyz.app.repository*** package, and is defined as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "aas", path = "aas")
public interface MyInterfaceRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass, Long>, 
                                                 MyCustomInterface {
  ...
}
```

Then, I also have a ***MyInterfaceRepositoryImpl.java***, that lives in ***com.xyz.app.repository***, that provides an implementation for ***MyCustomInterface.java***, that also lives in ***com.xyz.app.repository***.

Starting my application I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xyz.app.repository.MyInterfaceRepository] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at com.xyz.app.Application.main(Application.java:60)
```

I already checked, and indeed if I put ***MyInterfaceRepository.java*** and ***MyInterfaceRepositoryImpl.java*** in the same package as ***Application.java***, ***com.xyz.app***, than it works.

It seems that Spring is not able to load the beans from a different package than the one where ***Application.java*** is.

Also, I tried replacing the ***@SpringBootApplication*** with these:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.xyz.app.repository"})
```

Same issue.. Any idea?

Comment: subpackages are automatically scanned so anything that's under `com.xyz.app` would work. Just remove the custom declaration.

Comment: Why do you even have an implementation? You are using Spring Data so the isn't needed

Comment: Do you actually have `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo` dependency?

Comment: I have an implementation because I need it for my custom method defined in MyCustomInterface. Essentially, I do as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository

Comment: And yes, I do have spring-boot-starter-data-mongo

Comment: Are there any other exceptions? When you add `scanBasePackages` explicitly, it will only scan the packages listed. So other classes like configuration may not be scanned. Try to replace the package with the root package and see if it works.

Comment: I also have another Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. Alas, changing the package does not seem to help

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring mongodb, you don't need to use annotation: `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "aas", path = "aas")`

You also can use `@Autowired` in the `MyInterfaceRepository`.

Comment: Well, if I do this then I need to provide an implementation for all MongoRepository methods..

Comment: You don't need to do that. Please try using it.

Comment: I did, I put @Autowired before _public interface ... _ and it asks me for an implementation of all MongoRepository methods in some class..

Comment: Why should he use Autowired in the interface? The interface doesn't have any fields which could be autowired, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: you use something like that `public interface YourRepository extends CrudRepository<YourDocumentClass, String>`. You can `@Autowire YourRepository` anywhere because spring framework had implemented the interface.

Answer (score 0):

On your application class/main class add @EnableMongoRepositories.  You should have something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz.app"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz.app.repository"}, repositoryBaseClass = MyInterfaceRepositoryImpl.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

See [EnableMongoRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html) for more details about the annotation.

Comment: Agrh, no, does not seem to help