# What is the difference between MongoRepository and MongoOperation.

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I am doing one POC and got confused what should i use either MongoRepository or MongoOperation beacuse internally both uses MongoTempletes only. Please suggest with proper example.Thanks in advance :).

Comment: MongoOperations is an interface and MongoTemplate is an implementation class of it. Here is the difference between Mongotemplate and Mongorepository explained . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran