# Translate mongo document distinct into mongotemplate or mongorepository?

Tags: spring, mongotemplate, mongorepository

How i can translate this basic sentence to mongotemplate or mongorepository
I need find all distinct names in collection user

```
db.user.distinct('name');


@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Sample Json

```
 {
    "_id" : "12358",
    "name" : "HiMan",
    "description" : "sales category",
}
{
    "_id" : "791127",
    "name" : "HiMan",
    "description" : "",
}
{
    "_id" : "123123",
    "name" : "Rango",
    "description" : "sales Rango",
}
```

And i get: [ "Rango", "HiMan" ]

Comment: have you tried my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

MongoRepository is pretty straight forward:

```
public interface UserMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {     
}
```

Replace `String` with the type of your primary key. As far as methods are concerned, they follow a pretty easy pattern: `findOneByName(String name);` other options are `findAll`, `findFirst`, `findDistinct` etc.

So your repository may end up looking like:

```
public interface UserMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {     
    User findDistinctByName(String name);
}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) for more information.

Also, to address the differences between using a mongoRepository vs a mongoTemplate, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository)