# MongoTemplate vs MongoOperations which one to use

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

In my project we are using MongoTemplate, which is injected by spring

```
private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

I know mongo template implements MongoOperations, ApplicationContextAware, so we get context aware method with template, which we do not get if I use the mongo operation type object like below (spring will inject mongo template object in it)

```
private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;
```

My doubt is 
 1. Are we not violating "programming to interface" paradigm doing that 
 2. Which pattern should we use and why?

Comment: Check out the below post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository

Comment: Mongo operations - an interface that specifies a basic set of MongoDB operations. Implemented by MongoTemplate. Not often used but a useful option for extensibility and testability (as it can be easily mocked, stubbed, or be the target of a JDK proxy).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html